# Get Shapes By Name

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, shapes

I am creating a win app in VS2012 , in one form I create many Rectangle Shapes And Line Shapes by Calling a method dynamically , now I need set a name or index for these shapes to Get or Set Shapes properties in another method and ... , I want to write the code like this :

```
TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)Controls["TextBox1"];
```

but this line works with Controls and Rectangles And Shapes are Shapes(Shape Data Type);
what can I do for this . Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add them to a Dictionary or something like that when you create them ?

Then you could access them quite easily

e.g:

```
var myShape = myDictionary["myShapeName"];
```

EDIT:

To declare a Dictionary (use the type of your shapes instead of object):

```
Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

To add something in it:

```
myDictionary.Add("unique name", myObject);
```

For more information about the Dictionary class see the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: maybe write more description ? how to store and recover shape in dic and ? anyway tnx so much